# Field not refreshed in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-composition-api

I have a couple inputs on my page, data.qty, data.price, data.total, ...
I have a watch function to update the total when qty or price are updated.
If I watch console.log(data.value.total) It gives for example 40 but the input has a different value.
Precisely if I type 1, no update then if I continue 2 (12) then the total is updated with the previous input (1) and so on...

```
<v-row dense>
            <v-col cols="4">{{$tc('Purchase')}}</v-col>
            <v-col cols="2">
              <input v-model="data.quantity" type="text" class="pdg-input" />
            </v-col>
            <v-col cols="2">
              <input v-model="data.price" type="text" class="pdg-input" />
            </v-col>
            <v-col cols="2">
              <input v-model="data.total" type="text" readonly class="pdg-input" />
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
```

...

```
watch(
  () => data.value.quantity,
  () => {
    updatePurchaseTotal();
  }
)
```

...

```
function updatePurchaseTotal() {
...
data.value.total = data.value.quantity * data.value.price;
console.log(data.value.price) ; // prints 40
console.log(data.value.total) ; // prints 40 but different value in the field
...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You do not need to use the watch function since you are using two way
>   bind. **You also should not use v-model for the total field since you are not
>   actually entering any value in there.** This is why computed properties
>   are available.

`import { computed } from @vue/composition-api`

since you are using composition api and then it should update normally

To use:

```
  setup(){
     const total = computed(() => {
        return data.value.quantity * data.value.price
      })
      return { total }
     }
```

Do not forget to return the computed property. with this you will be able to make use of total in your component by just calling `total` and it should update automatically when the other entries are changed.

If you would like to compress your computed property because they match you can return an object

```
 setup(){
        const properties = computed(() => {
            return {
                   total: data.value.quantity * data.value.price
                   margin: other_function()
                   }
          })
          return { properties }
         }
```

You could chose to call the function first and attach the result to a key as its value instead of just calling it within the object(as its value) like i specified above

With this you will be able to work with `properties` computed property as an object all around you components

Comment: I'll give it a try but I update many fields at the same time : margins, ratio...

Comment: It works but I have many computed fields, I wish I could have a computed object for example margins:{price, rate...} instead of marginPrice, marginPriceRate...

Comment: Once easy work around would be to make the object your computed property returns to be an object. such that the key is the name of the property and the value is a function like the one above. I updated my answer to for a clearer description

Answer (score 0):

You should use `watch` property like this.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    data: {
      quantity: 4,
      price: 10,
      total: 40
    },

  },
  watch: {
    'data.quantity': function(val) {
      console.log(val);
      this.data.total = this.data.price * val;
    },
    'data.price': function(val) {
      console.log(val);
      this.data.total = val * this.data.quantity;

    }

  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model.number="data.quantity" type="text" class="pdg-input" />
  <input v-model.number="data.price" type="text" class="pdg-input" />
  <input v-model="data.total" type="text" readonly class="pdg-input" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank your for your answer but I'm using composition-api, the syntax is different, no more access to this.